# dynamic array declaration in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, declaration

I have seen two ways to declare a dynamic array in C++. One is by the use of new operator:

```
int *arr = new int [size];
```

and other is directly declaring:

```
int arr[size];
```

NOTE: Here note that size is a variable whose value will be provided by the user at runtime.
Question is what is the best approach to declare a dynamic array in C++?

Comment: The second one is not standard C++, it is a compiler extension (that *some* compilers support)

Comment: @Gaurav Sahu What is the question?

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Comment: The second syntax is valid C but not C++. The 2 things have different meaning, the C++ construct is translated to C as `int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size). The C construct cannot be translated to C++ directly.

Comment: Why not use std::vector-std::array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your question is, "what is better?".

The second, the direct creation of the array, creates the array on the stack, the first on the heap. The second is called variadic-length-array (VLA), which is nonstandard C++ and not portable, but in C it is standard. The GNU C++ compilers support that, but others do not support that. Internally the array is allocated as with `alloca`(POSIX)/`__builtin_alloca`(GNU), which extends the stackframe. The variadic-length-array can *smash* your stack with a big size (maybe produces a SIGSEGV, but may also corrupt other data), while the new-operator throws a catchable exception. (However, using recursive functions can *smash* your stack the same way...). It is not a bad practice to use VLAs, when you know the size is relatively small. The VLAs can even improve the performance, when the array needs to be allocated multiple times (the allocation of the VLA is faster than the allocation on the heap). Because of the VLA *living* on the stack it doesn't need to be `free`d/`delete`d, it is automaticly freed when the function quits. 
This applies to the GNU-Compilers: VLAs do call the destructors on destruction, but the memory allocated with `alloca`/`__builtin_alloca` is just going to be freed at the end of the function as memory (allocated with `malloc`) freed with `free`.

As conclusion, I think the allocation with the `new` is better for most problems. But the VLA is good for fast memory allocation local in a function. There is no portable approach to return a VLA from a function (without hacking through assembly) (You can return arrays with constant size from a function, however it needs to be specified in the signature). For this, there is `std::array` and `std::vector`, I recommend to use that instead of hand made memory management (the allocation with `new` and `delete` or Cs `malloc` and `free`), which is not freed when an exception is raised. Memory-management should always be nested in the constructor and destructor of a class, if you need to use such functions. The destructors are always called, when the object goes out of scope, so there are no memory leaks.

One thing you cannot do with VLAs and `new`/`delete` is fast resizing. Even `std::vector` does not use it. It is done with the C-function `realloc`, which tries to keep the buffer inplace. When you need this you can easily design a `std::vector`-like class, which should call `free` in the destructor. To destruct an element you call `element.~T()`, where `T` is the type of `element`.

However `std::vector` tries to improve the performance of resizing by allocating a buffer with additional space.

Comment: `alloca` is neither standard C++ nor C

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two methods is that the first allocates memory from the Free-store(Heap), the second one allocates from the stack. In fact the second one is not good to use because the stack memory is very limited in space compared to the heap. Also the first statement obviously returns a pointer to the first element in the allocated memory while the second one returns the array itself.